# How to set value of hidden field in mvc 5 view based on the onchange event of a control that is in an index

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a list inside a model like this:

```
public class model
{
    public string value1 {get;set;}
    public string value2 {get;set;}
    public List<subModel> value3 {get;set;}
}

public class subModel
{
    public string value4 {get;set;}
    public string value5 {get;set;}
    public bool dirtyFlag {get;set;}
}
```

In my view, I am able to display this model like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.subModel.Count; i++ )
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.subModel[i].value4, Model.value4Lookup, 
          Model.subModel[i].value4, new { onchange = "MarkRecordDirty()" })
}
```

I want to be able to use the onchange event of the drop down list to set the dirtyFlag to true, but I'm not sure how to pass the value of [i] in Model.subModel[i].value4 to the javascript function MarkDirtyRecord()

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if *all you need to do* is pass the value of `i` to the client-side code, you can do that with string concatenation:

```
onchange = "MarkRecordDirty(" + i.ToString() + ")"
```

Each iteration of the loop creates new output, so the resulting tags would have different outputs:

```
... onchange="MarkRecordDirty(0)" ...
... onchange="MarkRecordDirty(1)" ...
... onchange="MarkRecordDirty(2)" ...
... onchange="MarkRecordDirty(3)" ...
etc.
```

As for the exact question asked, that should do the trick.  However, I suspect that there could be more to the issue at hand.  At the very least this is going to make the code fairly brittle with an assumed dependency on ordering of records.  That might not cause any problems, but then again it might.  I can't know without knowing more about the overall solution you're building.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed. The number and order of records is static when it gets to this point, so assumed dependency is fine. I just needed a way to mark the correct record when it had been changed so that when the model is sent back to the controller I can loop through the records and call the save function on only the records that have a dirty flag marked true.